# Add second QuickSearchToolbar for datagrid

Tags: reactjs, node.js, material-ui

so i have this data grid i want have another QuickSearchToolbar the first one just regular search for mui data grid while i want to another one like that only search for certain field  which is the posted by full_name field is it posibe have two QuickSearchToolbar in data grid componentthis the code :

```
/* eslint-disable react-hooks/exhaustive-deps */
// ** React Imports
import { ChangeEvent, forwardRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import Link from 'next/link'

// ** Third Party
import axios from 'axios'

// ** MUI Imports
import Box from '@mui/material/Box'
import Card from '@mui/material/Card'
import Typography from '@mui/material/Typography'
import CardHeader from '@mui/material/CardHeader'
import InputLabel from '@mui/material/InputLabel'

import { DataGrid, GridColumns, GridRenderCellParams } from '@mui/x-data-grid'

// ** Custom Components
import CustomAvatar from 'src/@core/components/mui/avatar'
import QuickSearchToolbar from './search-table'

// ** Types Imports
import { ThemeColor } from 'src/@core/layouts/types'
import { DataGridRowType } from 'src/layouts/components/user/userTypes'

// ** Utils Import
import { getInitials } from 'src/@core/utils/get-initials'

// ** Data Import
import { Button, ButtonBase, Dialog, FormControl, Grid, IconButton, MenuItem, Select, TextField, Tooltip } from '@mui/material'
import { Icon } from '@iconify/react'

import adminapi from 'src/configs/admin'
import { configDefaultHeadersWithToken } from 'src/configs/utils'
import socmedApi from 'src/configs/socmedApi';

import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

import { useRouter } from 'next/router'


import Slide from '@mui/material/Slide';
import { TransitionProps } from '@mui/material/transitions';
import { wrap } from 'module'



  
const Transition = forwardRef(function Transition(
    props: TransitionProps & {
        children: React.ReactElement;
    },
    ref: React.Ref<unknown>,
) {
    
    return <Slide direction="up" ref={ref} {...props} />;
});


const columns: GridColumns = [
    {
        flex: 0.220,
        minWidth: 160,
        field: 'full_name',
        headerName: 'Posted By',
        renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
            const { row } = params
            const stateNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 6)
            const states = ['success', 'error', 'warning', 'info', 'primary', 'secondary']
            const color = states[stateNum]

            return (

                <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>

                    <CustomAvatar
                        skin='light'
                        color={color as ThemeColor}
                        sx={{ mr: 3, fontSize: '.8rem', width: '1.875rem', height: '1.875rem' }}
                    >
                        {getInitials(row.full_name ? row.full_name : 'John Doe')}
                    </CustomAvatar>
                    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                        <Typography noWrap variant='body2' sx={{ color: 'text.primary', fontWeight: 600 }}>
                            {row.full_name}
                        </Typography>
                    </Box>

                </Box>
            )
        }
    },
    {
        flex: 0.220,
        minWidth: 50,
        field: 'post_time',
        headerName: 'DATE',
        renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
            
            const { row } = params

            const datetimeString = row.post_time;
            const datetimeParts = datetimeString.split(' ');
            const date = datetimeParts[0];
            const hour = datetimeParts[1];

            return (
                <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>

                    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                        <Typography noWrap variant='body2' sx={{ color: 'text.primary', fontWeight: 600 }}>
                        {date} | {hour}
                        </Typography>
                        {/* <Typography noWrap variant='body2' sx={{ color: 'text.primary', fontWeight: 600 }}>
                            {date}
                        </Typography> */}

                    </Box>

                </Box>
            )
        }
    },

    {
        flex: 0.2,
        minWidth: 120,
        headerName: 'SOCIAL MEDIA',
        field: 'channel_id',
        renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
            const { row } = params
           
            const myArray = row.channel_id.split(","); 
            const myArray1 = row.post_url?.split(","); 
            const status = row.status; 
            const iconsByElement = {
                facebook_page: 'logos:facebook',
                twitter_page: 'logos:twitter',
                instagram_page: 'skill-icons:instagram',
              };

            if (myArray.length > 0) {
               
                  const elementsWithIcons: string[] = myArray.filter((element : any )=> iconsByElement.hasOwnProperty(element));    
                  elementsWithIcons.sort();
                  
                return (
                <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                {elementsWithIcons.map((element, index) => {

                    const iconType = element as keyof typeof iconsByElement;

                    const idx = myArray.indexOf(iconType)
                    const link = `${myArray1?.[idx] ?? ''}`;

                    if (status === 0) {

                    return (
                            <Icon
                                key={index}
                                icon={iconsByElement[iconType]}
                                style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }}
                            />
                        );
                    } else {

                        return (
                            <a
                            key={index}
                            href={link}
                            target="_blank"
                            rel="noopener noreferrer"
                            style={{ textDecoration: 'none', color: 'inherit' }}
                            >
                                <Icon
                                key={index}
                                icon={iconsByElement[iconType]}
                                style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }}
                                />
                            </a>
                            );

                    }
                    
                    })}
                    </div>
                );
            }
            else{
                // return (<Icon icon={"logos:" + myArray[0].split("_")[0]} style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginLeft: '10px' }} />)
                if (myArray[0] in iconsByElement) {
                    const iconType = myArray[0] as keyof typeof iconsByElement;
                    if (status === 0) {

                        return (
                            <Icon
                            icon={iconsByElement[iconType]}
                            style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginLeft: '10px' }}
                          />
                        );
                    } else {

                        return (
                            <a
                              href={params.row.post_url ?? ''}
                              target="_blank"
                              rel="noopener noreferrer"
                            >
                              <Icon
                                icon={iconsByElement[iconType]}
                                style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginLeft: '10px' }}
                              />
                            </a>
                              );
                    }
                   
                    }
                 
            }

            // if (myArray.indexOf("facebook_page") > -1) {
            //     //In the array!
            // } 

            // if (row.channel_id === 'facebook_page') {
            //     return (<Icon icon="logos:facebook" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginLeft: '10px' }} />)

            // }
            // if (row.channel_id === 'twitter_page') {
            //     return (<Icon icon="logos:twitter" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginLeft: '10px' }} />)

            // }

            // if (row.channel_id === 'instagram_page') {
            //     return (<Icon icon="logos:instagram" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginLeft: '10px' }} />)

            // }

            // if (row.channel_id === 'twitter_page,instagram_page') {
            //     return (
            //         <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            //             <Icon icon="logos:twitter" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }} />
            //             <Icon icon="logos:instagram" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }} />
            //         </div>

            //     );
            // }

            // if (row.channel_id === 'facebook_page,instagram_page') {
            //     return (
            //         <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            //             <Icon icon="logos:facebook" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }} />
            //             <Icon icon="logos:instagram" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }} />
            //         </div>

            //     );
            // }

            // if (row.channel_id === 'twitter_page,facebook_page') {
            //     return (
            //         <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            //             <Icon icon="logos:twitter" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }} />
            //             <Icon icon="logos:facebook" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }} />
            //         </div>

            //     );
            // }


            // if (row.channel_id === 'facebook_page,twitter_page') {
            //     return (
            //         <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            //             <Icon icon="logos:facebook" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }} />
            //             <Icon icon="logos:twitter" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }} />
            //         </div>

            //     );
            // }


            // if (row.channel_id === 'twitter_page,instagram_page,facebook_page') {
            //     return (
            //         <div style={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
            //             <Icon icon="logos:facebook" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }} />
            //             <Icon icon="logos:instagram" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }} />
            //             <Icon icon="logos:twitter" style={{ fontSize: '17px', marginRight: '10px' }} />
            //         </div>

            //     );
            // 
             
        }
    },
    {
        flex: 0.2,
        minWidth: 120,
        headerName: 'TITLE',
        field: 'title',
        renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
            const { row } = params

            return (
                <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>


                    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                        <Typography noWrap variant='body2' sx={{ color: 'text.primary', fontWeight: 600 }}>
                            {row.title}
                        </Typography>
                    </Box>

                </Box>
            )
        }
    },
    {
        flex: 0.2,
        minWidth: 120,
        headerName: 'MESSAGE',
        field: 'message',
        renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
            const { row } = params

            return (
                <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>


                    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                        <Typography noWrap variant='body2' sx={{ color: 'text.primary', fontWeight: 600 }}>
                            {row.message}
                        </Typography>
                    </Box>

                </Box>
            )
        }
    },
    {
        flex: 0.134,
        minWidth: 50,
        headerName: 'Status',
        field: 'status',
        
        renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {
            const colorMap: { [key: string]: string } = {
                'Pending': '#ffc107',
                'Approved': 'black',
                'Scheduled': 'blue',
                'Posted': '#28c76f',
                'Rejected': 'red',
              };
            const { row } = params
            let statusData = ""
            if (row.status == 0) {
                statusData = "Pending";
            }
            if (row.status == 1) {
                statusData = "Approved";
            }
            if (row.status == 2) {
                statusData = "Scheduled";
            }
            if (row.status == 3) {
                statusData = "Posted";
            }
            if (row.status == -1) {
                "Rejected";
            }
            // const [statusData, setStatusData] = useState("");
            // useEffect(() => {
                // if (row.status == 0) {
                //     setStatusData("Pending");
                // }
                // if (row.status == 1) {
                //     setStatusData("Approved");
                // }
                // if (row.status == 2) {
                //     setStatusData("Scheduled");
                // }
                // if (row.status == 3) {
                //     setStatusData("Posted");
                // }
                // if (row.status == -1) {
                //     setStatusData("Rejected");
                // }
            // }, []);

            const statusColor = colorMap[statusData] || 'black'; // Default to black if not found in the map

            return (

                <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', alignItems: 'center' }}>
                    <Box sx={{ display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' }}>
                        <Typography noWrap variant='body2' sx={{ color: statusColor , fontWeight: 600 }}>
                            {statusData}
                        </Typography>
                    </Box>

                </Box>
            )
        }
    },

    {
        minWidth: 100,
        field: 'action',
        headerName: 'Action',
        renderCell: (params: GridRenderCellParams) => {

            const { row } = params;
            const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken")

            // const [Open, SetOpen] = useState(false);

            // const [IdClick] = useState<any>()


            // const handleClose = () => {
            //     SetOpen(false);
            // };

            const handleDelete = () => {

                Swal.fire({
                    title: 'Are you sure?',
                    text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
                    icon: 'warning',
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                    cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                    confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.isConfirmed) {
                        axios.delete(adminapi.deleteListPostAdmin + `/${row.id}`, configDefaultHeadersWithToken(token))
                            .then(() => {

                                Swal.fire(
                                    'Deleted!',
                                    'Your file has been deleted.',
                                    'success'
                                )
                                    .then(() => {
                                        window.location.reload();
                                    });
                            })
                            .catch((error) => {
                                console.error('Error deleting member:', error);
                            });
                    }
                });
            };
            if (row.status != 3) {

                return (
                    <>
                        <Grid className='text-end' sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>

                            <Tooltip title='View'>
                                <IconButton
                                    size='small'
                                    component={Link}
                                    sx={{ color: 'blue' }}
                                    href={`/manage-posting/detail/${row.id}`}
                                >
                                    <Icon icon="material-symbols:edit-sharp" />
                                </IconButton>
                                
                            </Tooltip>
                            <Tooltip title='Delete'>
                                <ButtonBase sx={{ marginRight: '8px' }} onClick={() => handleDelete()}>
                                    <Icon icon="material-symbols:delete" style={{ fontSize: '20px', color: 'red' }} />

                                </ButtonBase>
                            </Tooltip>

                            {/* <Dialog
                                open={Open}
                                fullScreen
                                TransitionComponent={Transition}
                                keepMounted
                                onClose={handleClose}
                                aria-describedby='alert-dialog-slide-description'
                            > */}
                                {/* <UbahProvinsiPopUp handleClose={handleClose} id={idClick} /> */}

                                {/* <Detail handleClose={handleClose} id={IdClick} /> */}
                            {/* </Dialog> */}
                        </Grid>
                    </>
                )
            }
            else {

                return (
                    <>
                        <Grid className='text-end' sx={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'flex-end' }}>


                            {/* <IconButton
                                size='small'

                                sx={{ color: 'text.secondary' }}

                            >
                                <Icon icon="material-symbols:edit-sharp" />
                            </IconButton> */}
                            <Tooltip title='View'>
                                <IconButton
                                    size='small'
                                    component={Link}
                                    sx={{ color: 'blue' }}
                                    href={`/manage-posting/detail/${row.id}`}
                                >
                                    <Icon icon="ph:magnifying-glass" />
                            
                                </IconButton>
                                </Tooltip>

                            <ButtonBase sx={{ marginRight: '8px' }} >
                                <Icon icon="material-symbols:delete" style={{ fontSize: '20px', color: 'gray' }} />

                            </ButtonBase>


                            {/* <Dialog
                                open={Open}
                                fullScreen
                                TransitionComponent={Transition}
                                keepMounted
                                onClose={handleClose}
                                aria-describedby='alert-dialog-slide-description'
                            > */}
                                {/* <UbahProvinsiPopUp handleClose={handleClose} id={idClick} /> */}

                                {/* <Detail handleClose={handleClose} id={IdClick} /> */}
                            {/* </Dialog> */}
                        </Grid>
                    </>
                )
            }


        }
    }
]

const TableColumns = () => {
    // ** States

    const [page, setPage] = useState(0);
    const [pageSize, setPageSize] = useState(5);
    const [filterModel, setFilterModel] = useState<any>();
    // const [filter, setFilter] = useState<any>('0');
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [rowCount, setRowCount] = useState(0)
    const [data, setData] = useState<DataGridRowType[]>([])
    const [searchText, setSearchText] = useState<string>('')
    const token = localStorage.getItem("accessToken")
    const router = useRouter();

    const data1: any = localStorage.getItem('userData')
    const userData = JSON.parse(data1) || null
    const full_name = userData.full_name;
    const role = userData.role;
        console.log('Role:', role);
    const [filter, setFilter] = useState<any>(role == 'owner' ? '0' : '')


    const [sortModel, setSortModel] = useState(
        columns.map(() => ({
                field: 'post_time',
                sort: 'desc',
            }))
    )
    const handleButtonClick = () => {
        router.push('/post');
    };
    
    const fetchData = async () => {
        console.log(filter)
        
        setIsLoading(true);
        try {
            let url = adminapi.getListPosting + `?page=${page + 1}&size=${pageSize}&search=${searchText}&sort=${sortModel[0].field} ${sortModel[0].sort}`
            if (filterModel) {
                url += `&query=${encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(filterModel.items))}`
            }
            if (filter) {
                url += `&filter=${filter}`

            }
            const response = await axios.get(url, configDefaultHeadersWithToken(token))
            const data = await response.data.result.data
            setRowCount(data[0])
            setData(data[1])
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error fetching data:', error)
        }
        setIsLoading(false);
    }
    
   

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchData()

    }, [page, pageSize, sortModel, filterModel, searchText,filter])

    const handleSearch = (searchValue: string) => {
        setSearchText(searchValue);
    };

    const handleChangeStatus = (filter: any) => {
        setFilter(filter.target.value);
    };

    return (

        <Card>
            <CardHeader title='List Post Admin' />
            <Grid sx={{ ml: 5, mb:5}}>
                <Button variant='contained' size='medium' onClick={handleButtonClick}><Icon icon="icons8:plus" width="25" height="25" />ADD</Button>
            </Grid>
            <Grid item sm={5} md={8.5} xs={5} lg={8.5} gap={2} display={'flex'} justifyContent={'flex-end'} ml={5}>
            <FormControl fullWidth size='small'>
                        <TextField
                            value={full_name}
                            label="Search by Full Name"
                            variant="outlined"
                            size="small"
                            />    
                        </FormControl>
                        <FormControl fullWidth size='small'>
                            <InputLabel id='status-select'>Select Status</InputLabel>
                            <Select
                                fullWidth
                                value={filter}
                                id='select-status'
                                label='Select Status'
                                labelId='status-select'
                                onChange={handleChangeStatus}
                                inputProps={{ placeholder: 'Select Status' }}
                            >
                                <MenuItem value=''>Select Status</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value='-1'>Rejected</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value='0'>Pending</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value='1'>Approved</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value="2">Scheduled</MenuItem>
                                <MenuItem value='3'>Posted</MenuItem>

                            </Select>
                        </FormControl>
                        
                    </Grid>
            <DataGrid
                rowCount={rowCount}
                loading={isLoading}
                pagination
                page={page}
                paginationMode="server"
                onPageChange={(newPage) => setPage(newPage)}
                autoHeight
                columns={columns}
                pageSize={pageSize}
                rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25, 50]}
                components={{ Toolbar: QuickSearchToolbar,}}
                disableColumnFilter

                rows={data}


                onPageSizeChange={newPageSize => setPageSize(newPageSize)}
                componentsProps={{
                    baseButton: {
                        variant: 'outlined'
                    },
                    toolbar: {
                        value: searchText,
                        clearSearch: () => handleSearch(''),
                        onChange: (event: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => handleSearch(event.target.value),
                        
                    }
                }}
                sortingMode="server"
                onSortModelChange={(newSortModel) => setSortModel(newSortModel as any)}
                filterMode="server"
                onFilterModelChange={(newFilterModel) => setFilterModel(newFilterModel as any)}
            />

        </Card>
    )
}

export default TableColumns
```

this how ui look right now
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLGS4.png)

expected the poted search by full_name is beceome searh quick filter like on the left